# CFPDFFORM removes all datasets from source PDF during populate! What to do?

Tags: coldfusion, dataset, livecycle, cfpdfform

I have a LiveCycle Dynamic PDF form that has lots of datasets where basic information are stored to feed dropdown fields. Here is an excerpt of its XML source:

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
   <MyDataForDropDowns>
         <Languages>
            <Language id=""/>
            <Language id="1">English</Language>
            <Language id="2">French</Language>
            <Language id="3">German</Language>
         </Languages>
   </MyDataForDropDowns>
<xfa:data xfa:dataNode="dataGroup"/>
</xfa:datasets>
...
</xdp:xdp>
```

I use cfpdfform to pre-fill this pdf form:

```
<cfpdfform source="pdf/FormA.pdf" 
               action="populate"  
               overwritedata="true"
               xmldata="#xmlStringFormData#">

</cfpdfform>
```

Form loads up and none of my dropdown fields binded to datasets work! Guess what, cfpdfform removed all my datasets. Opening the pdf sent by cfpfdform in Livecycle shows this:

```
...
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">  
   <xfa:data xfa:dataNode="dataGroup"/>
</xfa:datasets>
...
</xdp:xdp>
```

Does anyone know what is going on???

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: This is most likely a ColdFusion bug. I create a record in http://cfbugs.adobe.com bug# is 87010. You can vote for it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though you are missing your `destination` attribute, or was this simply an omission?

Comment: If destination is not provided to CFPDFFORM, it will display the result in the web browser and that was my intention.

Comment: I apologize. This is apparently what happens when I try answering questions from my iPad and get lazy on referencing documentation. I was, however, answering this question with `cfpdf` in mind. I will take a step back and see if I can get you the **correct** answer.